# Reading Gdal VRT format

Tags: gdal, vrt, gdalbuildvrt

How can I read a `gdal vrt` file with `GDALOpen` function?

I have a `vrt` file built with `gdalbuildvrt` and I want to read it using `GDALOpen`  but It returns a null dataset, Is it even possible?
In this code `poDataset` is `null`

```
GDALDataset  *poDataset;
        GDALAllRegister();

           poDataset = (GDALDataset *) GDALOpen( "home/m/3857/srtm_merged.vrt", GA_ReadOnly );
        if( poDataset != NULL )
        {

}
```

It seems vrt files are ony supported in a few gdals tools.

Here is VRT:

```
<VRTDataset rasterXSize="21746" rasterYSize="17369">
  <SRS>PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["X",EAST],AXIS["Y",NORTH],EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs"],AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]</SRS>
  <GeoTransform>  5.0093307430080175e+06,  5.1196462744776348e+01,  0.0000000000000000e+00,  4.3927264476078171e+06,  0.0000000000000000e+00, -5.1196462744776348e+01</GeoTransform>
  <VRTRasterBand dataType="Int32" band="1">
    <NoDataValue>-9999</NoDataValue>
    <ColorInterp>Gray</ColorInterp>
    <ComplexSource>
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">1.tif</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
      <SourceProperties RasterXSize="5344" RasterYSize="6593" DataType="Int32" BlockXSize="5344" BlockYSize="1" />
      <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="5344" ySize="6593" />
      <DstRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="3624.28574350654" ySize="4471.35402450199" />
      <NODATA>-9999</NODATA>
    </ComplexSource>
    <ComplexSource>
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">2.tif</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
      <SourceProperties RasterXSize="5529" RasterYSize="6439" DataType="Int32" BlockXSize="5529" BlockYSize="1" />
      <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="5529" ySize="6439" />
      <DstRect xOff="0" yOff="13147.5894347461" xSize="3624.84957383552" ySize="4221.45169215535" />
      <NODATA>-9999</NODATA>
    </ComplexSource>
    <ComplexSource>
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">3.tif</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
      <SourceProperties RasterXSize="5470" RasterYSize="6489" DataType="Int32" BlockXSize="5470" BlockYSize="1" />
      <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="5470" ySize="6489" />
      <DstRect xOff="10871.7953859191" yOff="4468.83771045391" xSize="10874.354045833" ySize="12900.1249366381" />
      <NODATA>-9999</NODATA>
    </ComplexSource>
    <ComplexSource>
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">4.tif</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
      <SourceProperties RasterXSize="5344" RasterYSize="6593" DataType="Int32" BlockXSize="5344" BlockYSize="1" />
      <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="5344" ySize="6593" />
      <DstRect xOff="10871.7953859191" yOff="0" xSize="3624.28574350655" ySize="4471.354024502" />
      <NODATA>-9999</NODATA>
    </ComplexSource>
  </VRTRasterBand>
</VRTDataset>
```

---

well to others may face the same problem, there must be a `/` at the beginning of vrt path

```
GDALDataset  *poDataset;
        GDALAllRegister();

           poDataset = (GDALDataset *) GDALOpen( "/home/m/3857/srtm_merged.vrt", GA_ReadOnly );
        if( poDataset != NULL )
        {

}
```

Comment: I have only interfaced with GDAL via python and bash, but I am certain that almost all GDAL tools work with vrts. In python, gdal.Open('blah.vrt') will open the vrt. Open your vrt in a text editor to make sure it is valid, then double-check your code.

Comment: @Jon thanks for your help, In fact I am confused about this problem, I want to use vrts as a mosaic and then easily read different subsets from them, But when gdalopen can not read them it is a big problem

Comment: According to the documentation (http://www.gdal.org/gdal_8h.html#a6836f0f810396c5e45622c8ef94624d4) it should be able to deal with virtual files. "This function will try to open the passed file, or virtual dataset name by invoking the Open method of each registered GDALDriver in turn. The first successful open will result in a returned dataset. If all drivers fail then NULL is returned and an error is issued."

Comment: Try opening a tif instead of vrt. If it works, following @MikkelLydholmRasmussen 's info, you may need to update your version of GDAL.

Comment: @MikkelLydholmRasmussen so you mean there is not any vrt driver installed? but gdalinfo returns vrt's information, so it is installed

Comment: well sorry for taking your time, My mistake was about path, there was a / needed at the start of file path

Comment: @MajidHojati I think standard procedure is to submit your solution as an answer, then accept it.

Comment: @MajidHojati don't forget to accept the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well to others may face the same problem, there must be a `/` at the beginning of `vrt` path

```cpp
    GDALDataset  *poDataset;
    GDALAllRegister();
            
    poDataset = (GDALDataset *) GDALOpen("/home/m/3857/srtm_merged.vrt",GA_ReadOnly );
    if( poDataset != NULL )
        {
        //Valid
        }
```

Comment: Please accept this answer (using the grey/green arrow to the left) so others will see this question listed as answered.

Comment: @Kersten sorry I just forgot to accept it after 2 days. thanks